# How to check if a variable has characters that are not allowed in?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a password program where it will display a score if certain requirements are met. But I am stuck on how to check if some characters are not allowed. If they are not allowed it should notify the reader.
Here is my code:

```
user_password = input("\nEnter your password:")
user_score = 0
user_length = len(user_password)
symbols = "$%^&*()_-+="

if len(user_password)>24:
    print("Your password is too long! It must be between 6 and 24")
elif len(user_password)<6:
    print("Your password is too short! It must be between 6 and 24")
elif len(user_password) >=6 and len(user_password) <= 24:
    lower = sum([int(c.islower()) for c in user_password])
    if lower > 0:
            user_score = user_score + 5
    upper = sum([int(c.isupper()) for c in user_password])
    if upper > 0:
            user_score = user_score + 5
    integer = sum([int(c.isdigit()) for c  in user_password])
    if integer > 0:
            user_score = user_score + 5
    for c in symbols:
            if c in user_password:
                    user_score = user_score + 5
    for c in user_password:
            if c not in symbols:
                    print("Some symbols you entered are not allowed")
                    break
```

I want it so that the program will end if a symbol is wrongly entered it. However when a wrong symbol is entered it displays the message the amount of times the symbol is entered. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which characters are not allowed?

Comment: Answered your question! Hope it helped, if so please consider marking it as correct. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Can you give an example of a password that results in multiple messages displayed?

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't explain fully in the question. I wanted it so that any other characters that aren't specified in the 'symbols' variable, the upper/lowercase and digits to be not allowed.

Comment: Also, if any characters such as lower/uppercase are entered it notifies the user that some symbols are not allowed because they aren't in the variable 'symbols'. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the last `for-loop` so that it fails `if c in symbols`, you had a `not` in there that was throwing the program off...

```
for c in user_password:
            if c in symbols:
                    print("Some symbols you entered are not allowed")
                    break
```

---

A shorter way to do this with just ``` 2``lines ``` would be to use `any`:

```
if any(c in symbols for c in user_password):
            print("Some symbols you entered are not allowed")
```

---

As a final note, you should try to keep your `indentation` width to a constant `4` spaces for `readablility`. I haven't done this in these snippets as you will be able to test them with your existing code, but ideally you should change them.

Answer (score 0):

Change `if c not in symbols:` to `if c in symbols:`

```
user_password = input("\nEnter your password:")
user_score = 0
user_length = len(user_password)
symbols = "$%^&*()_-+="

if len(user_password)>24:
    print("Your password is too long! It must be between 6 and 24")
elif len(user_password)<6:
    print("Your password is too short! It must be between 6 and 24")
elif len(user_password) >=6 and len(user_password) <= 24:
    lower = sum([int(c.islower()) for c in user_password])
    if lower > 0:
            user_score = user_score + 5
    upper = sum([int(c.isupper()) for c in user_password])
    if upper > 0:
            user_score = user_score + 5
    integer = sum([int(c.isdigit()) for c  in user_password])
    if integer > 0:
            user_score = user_score + 5
    for c in symbols:
            if c in user_password:
                    user_score = user_score + 5
    for c in user_password:
            if c in symbols:
                    print("Some symbols you entered are not allowed")
                    break
```

Hope this helps and welcome to SO!

Comment: Hi, sorry I didnt fully explain what I wanted with the program. Basically, the variable 'symbols' were the allowed characters and then I wanted it to be any other characters except the specified symbols, upper/lower case and digits to be dismissed. Thank you.